# Material which is not rendered but interacts with light

Tags: light

It's hard to explain this. The way I'm visualising it is by thinking of an invisible object which reflects light.

[image]

Let's say we this cube here with one face of it being lit up with a blue spotlight.

Now, let's treat the patch of blue light on the face of the cube as another discrete object (I understand it's physically impossible but bear with me).

I want to be able to keep that patch of blue light while making the cube disappear.

What I visualize in my head is a patch of blue light hovering.
My ultimate goal is to capture lighting information.

I hope this makes a little more sense.

Comment: Which render engine are you targeting? [Cycles, Internal ... ]

Comment: This is pretty vague and contradicting. Could you post some reference images?

Comment: Cycles and it's hard to get a reference for this. I'll try and explain more in an edit.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you could elaborate on why you want this/what you want to use this information for? You might be able to capture the lighting information you want by using [render passes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/passes.html).

Comment: I want to see if I can overlay it on an image and make synthetic lights.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a [Shadow Catcher](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/objects/object_data.html#shadow-catcher)

Comment: I think what you desire may be able to be achieved with the direct lighting pass and some compositing, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

In the object properties tab of the properties window, there is a section titled "Cycles Settings". If you uncheck the box "camera" under "Ray Visibility", that object will disappear from the render but still reflect light and cast shadows.
[image]

Comment: This wasn't what I wanted but thanks anyway.

Comment: @dixiepig Creating the setup described in the image of the question. Toggling the Camera visibility makes the cube and its reflection(of the light) invisible to the camera(including render).